# Huge delay in CompletableFuture join() method

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

So I'm working on an application that has to make 20+ HTTP calls at a time. Each one of them takes 2-3 seconds to get a response.  It's pretty slow to make these calls one at a time (40 seconds at best), so I am trying to send them asynchronously via CompletableFutures. This should allow me to make calls while I'm waiting for the response of others, in theory reducing the total time to maybe 4-5 seconds instead of 40.

I made a very similar setup to this tutorial I found at https://www.codepedia.org/ama/how-to-make-parallel-calls-in-java-with-completablefuture-example.

```
import org.codingpedia.example;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParallelCallsDemoService {

    @Inject
    RestApiClient restApiClient;

    private ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    public List<ToDo> getToDos(List<String> ids){

        List<CompletableFuture<ToDo>> futures =
                ids.stream()
                          .map(id -> getToDoAsync(id))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<ToDo> result =
                futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }


    CompletableFuture<ToDo> getToDoAsync(String id){

        CompletableFuture<ToDo> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return restApiClient.makeSomeHttpCall(id);
        }, es);

        return future;
    }

}
```

By all accounts it seems to be working - the calls all get sent at roughly the same time, and they all return in a couple seconds. But then I'm experiencing a huge delay of 30-40 seconds on this part:

```
        List<ToDo> result =
                futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This makes it take roughly the same time as sending serially, which baffles me.  How can it be that I'm getting all responses in a couple seconds but then there's a 30 second delay on joining them? It's almost as if (despite appearances) they're still being made serially. Why does the join take so long?

Comment: How do you determine that “the calls all get sent at roughly the same time”? Are you monitoring the HTTP traffic? In that case, what does the monitoring say about the completion of the HTTP operations?

Comment: I tried to replace `makeSomeHttpCall(id)` with a simple `LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));` and got everything completed in about 3 seconds as expected. Could you adapt your example to make it a [mre]? Also, are you waiting for your application to terminate? Because you have to properly shutdown your `ExecutorService` for that to happen (it doesn't use daemon threads by default).

Comment: @Holger My app logs when it sends/receives transactions so I know when they're happening, and I'm also confirming this with the logs of the service I'm calling.  I am starting to suspect that my problem may be caused to a resource constraint - it appears that I am maxing out my JVM and briefly throttling the CPU when it is calling join().  I am trying to figure out how to get around that.. my application is deployed to an AWS-esque platform and I've already maxed out the JVM specs as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out! Thanks everyone for your suggestions. Turns out it was nothing to do with my implementation of CompletableFutures.  When I receive a response from the service, I use JAXB to convert the java object to an XML string for logging purposes. I started looking at thread dumps when it was hanging, and realized it was actually the JAXB string conversion that the threads were waiting for (the response object is quite large). I took out that part, and the performance immediately improved to what it should have been.

Comment: Good that you found it! However, this shows why it is very important to provide a [mre]: it makes sure the actual source of the problem is there in the question – and it also helps you narrow down the question to that part, which sometimes will make you find it without even needing to write a question.

Answer (score -1):

There's a bit of a problem here

```
List<ToDo> result =
                futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think the stream you are using is not a parallel stream. Therefore, each call to map is waiting for the last call to finish. Changing `futures.stream()` to `futures.parallelStream()` should have an improvement. Of course if you are not using a machine with a single core.

Comment: I tried that and am seeing a very slight improvement, like its 35 seconds now instead of 40.  However I'm still seeing a huge 30+ second delay in the join() call despite my logs indicating that I'm receiving responses to all 20 calls within a few seconds.

Comment: The [supplyAsync()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)) method executes its `Supplier` in a separate thread, so the `CompletableFuture` is already parallelized. There should be no need for an additional parallel stream.

Answer (score -1):

we have encountered a similar problem. we have solved it using '.get(timeout)' method of CompletableFuture.

```
CompletableFuture[] array = (CompletableFuture[]) futures.toArray();
       try {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(array).get(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        //log error
    }
```

Place the timeout based on your real-time results. you can tweak the time using an external configuration.

Comment: What happens if  the `get` times out?

Comment: It throws an exception. It's like a resilience check. you can fine-tune it with external configuration based on the observation. I know join will be an efficient solution. but we can't make the end-user wait for such a long time if things go wrong.

Comment: Can you explain in further details how does cancelling the future helps in speeding up its successful completion?

Comment: I'm not cancelling the future. I'm just waiting for the future to complete in a given period of time.